# Constant vs Unchanged Variable?

Tags: variables, constants

Is there any advantage to using a constant (unchangable) than just not changing a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some program languages, declaring something to be constant will allow a compiler to make optimizations which would not otherwise be possible. Further, declaring something to be constant can be a useful way of documenting that there are places in the code which might be broken should the value change.

Unfortunately, some programming languages sometimes do evil things with things that are declared constant. For example, in some .net languages, if a value type which is declared read-only is passed by modifiable reference, the compiler will, rather than refusing to allow such an action, instead make a copy and pass that. Such implicit copying will impair efficiency, and may result in unexpected semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your language and compiler, a constant may get inlined & optimized when built.  Variables will likely eat up stack space even if it never changes.

Answer (score 1):

By making the value constant, the compiler can just substitute it. If you have `x / 2`, for example, the compiler can compute the value and use that instead of having to emit code to retrieve the value of `x` and then divide it by 2.

Also, you don't have to worry about accidentally changing the value. For example, in C-like languages you might accidentally type `if (x = 2)` when you meant `if (x == 2)` which will change the value of `x` if it's a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone maintaining your code in the future (including you) won't have to look around to see where (if anywhere) a constant is changed when finding a bug or adding a feature - they'll know right off the bat that it *can't* be changed.